Not able to predict using Hugging-face Transformers Trainer class
I am learning to finetune a pre-trained model but when I am trying to test the finetuned model, I am getting this error

IndexError: tuple index out of range

this is my google colab notebook and I am using this Kaggle dataset
while debugging I found some of the observations

when I pass the testing data with 'input_ids','attention_mask' and 'labels', I am able to get the predicted results but when I am passing the data without labels ie. when I pass only 'input_ids' and 'attention_mask' I am getting the error.

but when I pass only 'input_ids' and 'attention_mask' of the training data, I am getting the predicted value as well which I am not able to understand


I am stuck and not able to move any further, any assistance to solve the issue would be appreciated
